# Unable to observe an array of objects (mobx)

Tags: mobx

According to the docs: https://mobx.js.org/refguide/array.html

I should be able to observe an array.

> observe(listener, fireImmediately? = false) Listen to changes in this
>   array. The callback will receive arguments that express an array
>   splice or array change, conforming to ES7 proposal. It returns a
>   disposer function to stop the listener.

However I'm getting an exception when I do so within my app:

```
core.js:1350 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: [mobx] Cannot obtain administration from Neil Clayton,Ralph Lambert,Suzie Legg
    at invariant (mobx.module.js:2652)
    at fail$1 (mobx.module.js:2647)
    at getAdministration (mobx.module.js:1967)
    at observeObservable (mobx.module.js:3606)
    at observe (mobx.module.js:3603)
    at ObjectChangeTracker.webpackJsonp.683.ObjectChangeTracker.installObserverDirectlyOn (orm-change-detection.ts:258)
```

I'm unsure why getAdministration() is falling through.
I was under the impression I could pass anything into observe() (either a JS Object, real class or array thereof).

Am I mistaken that I can observe an array?

Comment: can you add your code here?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was trying to observe a direct 'Array'.

This was happening because I was iterating the parent object keys, and getting the values by doing parent[propertyName]. Where 'propertyName' is provided by some other object (i'm intentionally leaving out specifics so as to not complicate my answer).

**This was a couple of days ago now, but from memory this caused access via a getter, which had a side effect (returned a sorted array, new object, that wasn't observable).**

If instead I got the value by the private field directly, and then observed the actual ObservableArray, my problems disappeared.

So, no longer convinced my question is valid.
Code is here: https://github.com/scornflake/scheduler
(but not expecting anyone to take a look, it's reasonably convoluted at the moment)